# Android View class thread stopping while in loop in the second iteration

Tags: java, android

this is the view class:

```
public class Ball extends View implements Runnable {


    public Ball(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(500, 200);
        //setY(100);
        this.setLayoutParams(lp);
        Log.d("test", "Ball created");
        Thread t = new Thread(this);

        t.start();
    }


    public void run() {

        try {



           while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                float y = getY();

                Log.d("test", "first y: " + y);
               Log.d("test", "LINE --- LINE");
                y = y + 30;
               Log.d("test", "setting y: " + y);
                setY(y);

               Log.d("test", "before sleep");
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
               Log.d("test", "after sleep");
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
            Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Log.d("test", "onDraw called");
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int x = getWidth();
        int y = getHeight();
        int radius;
        radius = 100;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        canvas.drawCircle(0 + radius, 0 + radius, radius, paint);
        Log.d("test", "onDraw Ended");
    }

}
```

in the run method, inside the loop, if I change it to:

```
y = y;
```

or even:

```
y = 30; //or any other number
```

the thread keeps working, but if the code is:

```
y = y + 30; // or any other number
```

then in the second iteration(I don't know why exactly is the 2 iteration) after executing setY(y), it stops and no errors are throwed, I can't catch the cause of this, can anyone have some clues about what might be the reason of this?

I just want the ball to change the y position each second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite strange way to update data for animation purposes. There is built in method for such purposes: `postInvalidateDelayed`.

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //calculate data
    //animate it
    postInvalidateDelayed(1000 / 30);//request drawing 30 frames per second.  
}
```

Comment: wow, this really works, but still don't know why my code didn't work, anyway thanks